# Assigning dates to a image collection which don't have any date properties attached to it

Tags: google-earth-engine, date, digital-image-processing, propertyname

This is what I have done till now-

```
var image= ee.Image("users/rohithari1703/merged_IMD_raster_WGS84_collection");
//print(image);    

var CHIRPS = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY").filterDate('1990-12-31', '2022-01-01');
var MODIS = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1");
var bands = image.bandNames();
//print(bands);
var list = bands.map(function(n) { return image.select([n]) });
var collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(list);
//print(collection);    

var SPI16DayVis = {"opacity":1,"bands":["SPI_16Days"],"min":-4,"max":4,"palette":["d53e4f","fc8d59","fee08b","ffffbf","e6f598","99d594","3288bd"]};

//Create a list based on system index number of images
var listMillis = collection.aggregate_array('system:index');
print(listMillis);    

//Turns the millis format of the list into a serial date format
var listDates = listMillis.map(function(getDate){
  return ee.Date(getDate).advance(ee.Number.parse(shift), 'day');
});
print(listDates);
```

Can we somehow add dates (calendar range) as a property to the dataset? The dataset contains daily precipitation rasters for 31 years (IMD netcdf .25 gridded data is used here).

Link for the script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6739c4d5a07d10124e9b5771900ad849

link for the dataset: users/rohithari1703/merged_IMD_raster_WGS84_collection

Comment: I'm not clear on which collection you want to add dates to and where those dates should come from.